# Visual Studio Code double quote syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I just upgraded VS code to `v1.20.1` and now I have errors everywhere telling me to replace double quotes with single quotes.

First of, I'm thinking of disabling this feature, since I'm a double quote guy. I have checked my user settings(File->Preferences->Settings) and searched for any `tslint` validations that has got to do with quotes and couldn't find any.

[image]

Second of all, I thought to myself that maybe it could be good practice to use single quotes in JS and I should get used to it.

I though doubt this might be good practice, if not please do prove me wrong.

My question are:

- Is or will in the later feature using single quotes in JS will be considered as good practice?
- How do I disable double quotes validation in VS Code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using single or double quotes is a matter of programming taste, at least for me.

To disable quotes validation you need to edit tslint.json (or create it: Create a tslint json file command) in project's folder, find the rule "quotemark" and set the following:

```
"quotemark": [
      false
    ]
```

As you see, it is a linter configuration, instead of vscode one. More information of this rule on [tslint documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/quotemark/).

If you want to continue with your double quotes set:

```
"quotemark": [
      true,
      "double"
    ]
```

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution! :D

Comment: Can we just use single quote ' instead of ", Will it affect the code ?